# What Is the best long term, Fragmenting LAMP or beefing up hardware

Tags: linux, hosting, web

I currently have a VPS with apache, php and mysql running on it (got other stuff too, but they arent related to the web server). It has 8gb ram, 4 core intel atom (dont know the clock speed) and 100gb disk space. This has run fine for a while, but im hitting limits with the processing speed and disk space. I have maxed this server package out so i have to move somewhere else. The concern i have at the moment is everything is currently running off the 1 CPU. When a request is made the 1 CPU has to handle everything. Fine on a small scale, but im starting to hit limits and i need to decide where to go from here. I have 2 solutions and i dont know which is the best long term solution. I want to make this server change now and be well setup for the future. I know cloud is good and all for addon, but i need to know what i should do to best deal with my concerns.

Option 1) Upgrade to a fully dedicated server. Brings me from 8gb ram to 32gb, atom CPU to Intel  Xeon D D-1520 (4 core, 2,2ghz) and 4TB storage. This is great, but expensive and it sticks to the same model i have now where everything is running off the one machine.

Option 2) Fragment the system so that mysql is on its own server with 100% of the computers resources and then have a separate file system that contains all of the files. This way when a reqest is made 1 server can handle all of the files and the other deal with the sql. My concern here is that the fragmentation will mean longer request times. calling localhost is a lot faster than an external http request.

What is the best direction for me to go?